# How to know where the last file created by my current user is located?

Tags: bash, find, directory, zip, locate

I use Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial) with Bash 4.3.48(1) and `zip` 3.0.

In a file containing a bash script (`#!/bin/bash`) with many different functions, I also have this function used to create *a full database backup + document root backup in one zip file*:

```
imb() {
    drt="/var/www/html"
    date="$(date +%F-%T)"
    mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases | zip "$drt/db-$date.zip" - # Note the hyphen before this comment;
    zip -r "all_zipped-$date.zip" "$drt"/ -x "*/cache/*"
    rm -f "$drt/db-$date.zip"
}
```

I sourced the aformentioned file (`source ~/function.sh`) and executed `imb` in debug mode (`set -x`):

I was prompted for DB password and then some time passed (indicating DB backup created). Also, a verbose zip appeared (too long to paste or trace in terminal) indicating everything under document root was zipped.

Yet no backup appears under `/var/www/html/`.

### My question

Due to a comment I feel I should ask two questions, which I found similar but actually different:

1. Where did zip put my files (assuming this isn't a"file creation" in the sense of manual creation as with `touch`, for example)? Of course, files created and located somewhere by a processes, shouldn't necessarily be owned by my user.
2. How could I find out where the the last file created **by my current user**, was located?

I expected it to be located in `/var/www/html/`:

```
zip -r "all_zipped-$date.zip" "$drt"/ -x "*/cache/*"
```

but wasn't. I don't know an efficient way to know where it was created without running on the entire file tree of my system up from root (`/`), as this could take hours in that machine.

### Update

When writing this question I visited my home dir (`$HOME/`), there I found the file, but I don't know why it was created there instead under document root.

Comment: You have two slightly different zip commands there...

Comment: If you still have the output from the imdb run, the first few and last few lines of the zip command may be helpful. We don’t need to see the files it backed up, just whether it indicated where it put the zip file (or if it had trouble doing so).

Comment: Is your question, what was the last file that the current user touched (as you have stated it). OR Where did zip (that I have just this moment run) put my files?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor It's a good point: I think, and I might be wrong, that if I ran a command a `sudo` it isn't distinguishable (both the manual file creation and the function create a file owned by root).

Comment: @user9303970 that was not my point (being root or not), but this point is also valid.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I think these are very similar questions though I can see the your point they differ. I edited to state there are indeed two different questions here.

Comment: One of the site rules is one question per question.

Comment: From my experience this rule can have rare exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
zip -r "all_zipped-$date.zip" "$drt"/ -x "*/cache/*"
```

creates an archive in the current directory, whatever that happens to be (your home directory in this case).

If you want to create the archive in `${drt}`, you need to tell `zip`:

```
zip -r "${drt}/all_zipped-$date.zip" "$drt"/ -x "*/cache/*"
```

There’s no trivial way to find out where the last file was created by any given user; you’d need to use `find` and sort by decreasing timestamp. Using the last modification time as an approximation for creation time:

```
find . -user user9303970 -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n -k1,1 -r | head -n 1
```